# Replicate dynamic views in xcode

Tags: android, ios, xcode, model-view-controller, view

I have an android app with the following setup:

- A Slide out menu with heading item & sub-items
- A View to represent every heading item in the menu
- Access to the sub-items of the main header

See below for a walkthrough of the views.

[image: main menu]
[image: main menu with dropdown]
[image: selected menu item - either main heading or sub-heading-item]

How can I replicate this functionality in xcode? The screenshots display the android version of the app. Are there any frameworks that will easily allow me to implement this? If not what design pattern should I use?

In the android version I used the following classes:

- PageSlidingTabStripFragment
- public class ExpandableListAdapter
  extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
- public class CardFragment extends    SherlockFragment
- public class
  ContentListAdapter extends    ArrayAdapter

Thanks

Comment: You can implement the same functionality with the help of animation.

Comment: @サンディープ can you please expand?

Answer (score 0):

When you create view for slide out, set its frame negative so that the view will remain on the left hand side of your home view.When you press top left button use animation and change your slide view frame so that it is on home view.

For expanding the table cells,you can use the following third party library - SKSTableView. https://github.com/sakkaras/SKSTableView